# Is if .. else .. an idiomatic way of writing things in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

What would be an F# idiomatic way of writing the following ? Or would you leave this as is ?

```
let input = 5
let result = 
     if input > 0 && input  < 5 then
         let a = CalculateA(input)
         let b = CalculateB(input)
         (a+b)/2
     else
         CalculateC(input)
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it (although I have programmed just in OCaml, not F#)

Comment: Absolutely nothing "unidiomatic" here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one `if ... then ... else ...` I'd probably leave it like that, if you had more cases I'd either use pattern match with a when guard:

```
let result =
    match input with
    | _ when input > 0 && input < 5  -> ...
    | _ -> ...
```

or you might also want to look at active patterns: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> What would be an F# idiomatic way of writing the following ? Or would you leave this as is ?

There's nothing wrong with the way you've written it but here is another alternative (inspired by Huusom):

```
let input = 5
let result =
  if input>0 && input<5 then [A; B] else [C]
  |> Seq.averageBy (fun f -> f input)
```

Comment: Creating a sequence to average two values may seem a bit of an overkill, doesn't it? Would this actually create a .NET IEnumerable under the hood or would the compiler optimise this away?

Comment: @AlexanderRautenberg: This may well be overkill and it will certainly be a lot slower. I just wanted to provide a more elegant solution following Huusom's point that the original code did look like it might be dealing with longer sequences.

Comment: getting it now, didn't have the proper context. Within context, your solution looks clearly much more reasonable. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is minor stylistic change but I find this more readable:

```
let input = 5
let result = 
     if input > 0 && input < 5 then
         (calculateA input + calculateB input) / 2
     else
         calculateC input
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer because Robert is correct. But it looks like you are working with series of functions, so you could write it like this:

```
let Calculate input =
    let calc = function | [f] -> f input | fl -> fl |> List.map ((|>) input) |> List.sum |> (fun s -> s / fl.Length)
    if input > 0 && input < 5
        then calc [CalculateA; CalculateB]
        else calc [CalculateC]
```

You could decompose to something with this signature: `((int -> int) list) -> ((int -> int) list) -> (int -> bool) -> int -> int` and then build your function by applying the first 3 parameters.

Comment: Well, yes it is :) But the original question looks like "if input satifies this, then calculate the average of these functions, otherwise just calculate this function".

And, I just found List.averageBy - damn.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment but why not `(if input>0 && input<5 then [A; B] else [C]) |> Seq.averageBy (fun f -> f input)` rather than an unnecessary special case and a transsiberian pipeline of superfluous combinators. :-)

Comment: Because I, stupidly, did not check the List or Seq modules first, I am so sorry... :)